# Transfer ERC 20 tokens from a wallet which has no eth

Tags: erc-20

I've a wallet-A which has 500 Tokens(ERC20) but it has 0 eth and I want to transfer these 500 Tokens from the wallet-A to wallet-B and wallet-B have eth.so how would I do it?

Comment: if it is a normal minimal erc20 contract with no authorities or support of signature approvals then you can't do that

Comment: it has simple approval function

Comment: A simple approval function needs a transaction. if you haven't approved another address before to send the tokens on your behalf then you cannot do it now without eth.

Answer (score 0):

Send your eth to wallet-A. wallet-A without any gas can't do anything but read.